# I don't fully understand Media Queries

Tags: css

Could someone just give a run down? Like if you had buttons and images, and a footer or something? Does it all go into one Media Query or is it separated? I'm very confused.

Comment: What media queries do is allow you to specify CSS rules for specific device sizes. These rules that are declared in media queries only execute when the browser is at a certain width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @Berdesdan said, Media queries set up specific styling so that your website can relate to screen sizes, etc.

For me, it depends on how long the classes in each section of my Style Sheet is. I usually have lots of classes for my header, footer and other section of my site. So I just add a Media Query under each section of my CSS. For instant;

```
            /* Header Styles */

            .header { width:100%; }
            .header ul { }
            .header ul li { }
            .header ul li a {}

            @media (min-width:768px){
              .header { width:80%; }
            }

            /* Footer Styles */

            .footer { width:100%; }
            .footer ul { }
            .footer ul li { }
            .footer ul li a {}

            @media (min-width:768px){
              .footer { width:80%; }
            }
```

In this way, I can edit each section and their media query together, one after another. Basically, you can have as many media queries in your CSS file as you want. No limit.

I hope this explains. Try checking out resources in the w3schools.com link and other resources on Media Queries.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries set up specific css rules at certain 'flags'.

They can be related to the screen, to set up specific css rules when some-one prints a document, or for screenreaders.

Read more on the following links.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp